# Running libgdx project on a desktop with Android studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I followed this link http://strivinglife.com/words/Post/Configuring-a-libGDX-project-to-run-as-a-desktop-application-in-Android-Studio on setting up to run libgdx project on a desktop computer. I was able to run it on the simulator. I get this error in the debugger. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? It says that it didn't found badlogic.jpg but the very same code runs on a simulator so I don't really get it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a `Run Configuration` issue. You can fix this by following the [official tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project) on creating `Run configurations` correctly for `libgdx`, esspecially the part describing the `Desktop` configuration.

Explanation: I'm guessing `badlogic.jpg` is in the `android` project, under the `assets` directory. When running the project for `android` that's OK, but when running for `Desktop` extra steps need to be taken in order for the app to take the assets from the correct place. This is what the `Run configuration` is for.

Comment: You were spot on. Thank you! You may noticed at the top of the screenshot this error: " WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h. "  That error looks strange because I am not playing any sound.

Comment: You should open a separate question for that, unless [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098495/java-carbon-component-warning-on-runtime-os-x) answers it.